# In android Oreo localization is not working

Tags: android, locale, android-8.0-oreo

In android Oreo Localisation is not working. All strings are displayed in device language only. Can some one help how to change set and get default locale?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47650872/6401241