# Not able to get English resource strings in Oreo

Tags: android, internationalization

I have met similar issues as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165311/how-to-change-android-o-oreo-api-26-app-language), I have already followed the rules to override attachBaseContext of Activity to provide the wrapped context, but still, there is some Activities not showing English.

One of the strangest thing is that, I debugged to evaluate the activity's resource's configuration, and found it was "en" already. The pictures is showing below:

[image]

[image]

I have checked the strings.xml under the default values folder, it is already written in English;

Comment: ????? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want the resource to read the English version strings.xml under values folder. I have updated the resource configuation to en, which is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165311/how-to-change-android-o-oreo-api-26-app-language