# Not able to programmatically change the locale in Oreo

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

I have a requirement to change my application language from English to Hindi.I am not able to do so in Android 8.0

```
public static void setUpLanguage(SqrrlApplication application, String languageIsoCode) {
        try {
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageIsoCode);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Resources res = application.getResources();
            Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                config.setLocale(locale);
                application.getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(config);
            }else{
                config.locale = locale;
            }
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please Note: However, if I change my device language from device settings, my app changes to hindi version.

I have 'values-hi' folder in res having the hindi strings.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Android O / Oreo / api 26 app language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165311/how-to-change-android-o-oreo-api-26-app-language) and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705739/android-n-change-language-programmatically

Comment: does you locale gets changed when app is restarted ?

Comment: @Gautam No, it doesn't affect when i restart the app.

Comment: even i am using the same code to update locale, but all of my activities extends a BaseActivity and overrides attachBaseContext method. Inside this i call  super.attachBaseContext({By calling setUpLanguage method which returns context that is passed initially}) .

Comment: Do i need to use attachBaseContext method ?

Comment: yes try overriding it inside activity