# Default string values are taken when a theme(dark mode) is changed, how to avoid this?

Tags: android, android-resources

I am doing a project where in i thought of providing "Localization" and "Dark Mode" for users.

For achieving Localization -> I have defined defined different string resources for different Locales under values-bn, values-es, values-hi, values-in, etc.

For changing Locale manually, i have used this code ->

```
         Locale l = new Locale("our_locale_string");//It may be en,hi,..  etc.
        Locale.setDefault(l);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = l;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I have used two styles.xml files for toggling between themes

For Light theme:

```
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
      </style>
```

For Dark theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

For changing theme to the overall app, i am using ->

```
     if (mode) {   //mode is a boolean variable to toggle b/n themes
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
```

I am able to achieve localization in light theme and also i am able to change to dark mode for the overall app. Here comes the problem, when i change the theme them respective strings are not used, instead default strings.xml(english generally)  is used. How can i make it to use corresponding locale strings.xml .

My resource directory structure in "Project view"

res/values
res/values-hi
res/values-zh
  .
  .
  .
res/values-es
and for night mode, i have res/values-night/styles.xml

I have also tried creating nigth mode resource files, for each of the above different string files in values-xx folders like values-hi-night for example but that doesn't work.

Comment: Checkout the answers in this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/47165311/7592063. This may help you.

Comment: Yeah some parts of my app are not translated. @Rajnishsuryavanshi  very useful. But my problem still exists, some parts are not translated

Comment: Hi @GaneshChowdharySadanala did you get any fix for this? i am also facing same issue. Could you please share if you get fix. Thank you.